# C# listbox does not display fields from .accdb file

Tags: c#, database

Im new with this thing, trying to create program with listbox which will show column of items from .accdb file

i have: oleDbConnection1, oleDbDataAdapter1 and dataSet1

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oleDbSelectCommand1.Parameters[0].Value = "%";   // if i understand correctly, it works like filter
            oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet1);
        }
```

the program does not show any errors in compilation and running mode, but listbox dont have any item

listbox have properties of DataSource and DisplayMember, can problem be with my database file? because i dont see any errors, that means it completely transfers all data...

thanks for the reply in advance

**upd:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**finded my mistake, instead of "dataSet1" i shall to place "dataTable1"**

[image]

but i still dont understand why filter with parameters dont works well

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                oleDbSelectCommand1.Parameters[0].Value = textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%";
                dataTable1.Clear();
                oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dataTable1);

        }
```

**finded another mistake, need to add command "WHERE ..."**

[image]

**thanks to all who helped, question is closed**

Comment: You need to use a `BindingList` or `ObservableCollection<T>`. How is your ListBox wired-up to your `oleDbDataAdapter1` exactly?. Also, **please give your objects more descriptive names** than just `oleDbConnection1`. Do you name your family members `elderMale1` and `elderFemale1` instead of `mum` and `dad`?

Comment: i can but what it will do, i need to understand why it dont want to add items in listbox if they are connected with DataSource; its default names which dont really interference, if program lost links or had errors with them, it would have displayed errors

Comment: The c# application will only show values that are in the database.  Any missing fields are usually due to the data not being in the database.

Comment: i will add file for better view

Comment: this means that I did something wrong in transporting data, right? data in file is simple